# I am trying to sorting out dataframe in descending order, but negative values are sorted in reverse way

Tags: python, sorting, dataframe

I have two columns in my data frame: 
`['objects', 'values']`

I am trying to sort a dataframe  by  the column `'values'` such that

- All positive values are sorted in descending order
- All the negative values are actually ascending order

example)

```
    values  objects
    2.0     a
    5.0     b
    -2.0    c
    -1.0    d
    0.5     e
```

Expected Result:

```
    values  objects
    5.0     b
    2.0     a
    0.5     e
   -2.0     c
   -1.0     d
```

Comment: why did you undo the edit? @coldspeed edit made the question readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'values': [ 2, 5, -2, -1, 0.5], 'objects': [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']})
df = pd.concat([df[df['values'] >=0].sort_values(by=['values'], ascending=False), 
           df[df['values'] < 0].sort_values(by=['values'])])
```

Comment: df = pd.concat([df[df['values'] >=0].sort_values(by=['values'], ascending=False), 
           df[df['values'] < 0].sort_values(by=['values'], ascending = False)]))